# Nameserver is absent on system restart

Tags: networking, 18.04, dns

Ubuntu 18.04

I have an issue with `systemd resolve --status` on system restart. Here is the output

```
$ sudo systemd-resolve status
status: resolve call failed: Unit dbus-org.freedesktop.resolve1.service not found.
```

Here is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.
```

There is no nameservers configured for now therefore no name can be resolved. But after running `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` it fixes just fine:

```
usr@pc:~$ sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service
usr@pc:~$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
# 127.0.0.53 is the systemd-resolved stub resolver.
# run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the actual nameservers.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

So any time I restart the laptop I have to manually `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service`. Is there a way to fix it?

Here is my `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf`

```
$ cat /etc/systemd/resolved.conf 
[Resolve]
DNS=8.8.8.8
#FallbackDNS=
#Domains=
#LLMNR=no
#MulticastDNS=no
#DNSSEC=no
#Cache=yes
#DNSStubListener=yes
```

UPD: I tried to commend the line `DNS=8.8.8.8` out and no name is resolved without it.

UPD: The `resolv.conf` is defined as

```
$ ls -la /etc/resolv.conf 
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jun  5 23:40 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

UPD: The file `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` got deleted on system restart so the symlink `/etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` is invalid when system is restarted. Manual `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` fixes the problem.

It seems the problem is about that `systemd-resolved` is simply not run on startup (for some unclear reason).

Comment: Why did you add `DNS=8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @Pilot6 Tried to fix an issue with broken DNS lookup and ended up with it. Is it unnecessary?

Comment: Remove it and all should work.

Comment: This is a wrong way of setting DNS.

Comment: @Pilot6 name resolution does not work without `DNS=8.8.8.8`

Comment: Is it a server? Then use netplan to set DNS.

Comment: What is the result of the terminal command: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @chili555 updated

Comment: Posiible duplicate: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150239/run-resolvconf-resolv-conf-ubuntu-18-04/1150294#1150294

Comment: @chili555 The file `/run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` got deleted on system restart so the symlink is invalid. The manual `sudo systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service` fixes the problem.

Comment: Are there any interesting clues here? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep resolv`

Comment: @chili555 I typed `sudo systemctl enable systemd-resolved` and removed `resolvconf` the problem disappeared.

Comment: @Pilot6 Setting DNS= in /etc/systemd/resolved.conf is not incorrect if you're using systemd-resolved.

Comment: I suggest you write an answer that I will upvote. The searchers with the same problem will appreciate it.