# resolv.conf file errors

Tags: networking, 20.04, dns, resolv.conf

I'm very new to Ubuntu (20.4.4) and for a few days now I can't connect to the internet. Well, I can get a WIFI connection, but there's no internet.
After digging I think I traced it back to my resolv.conf file.

I followed some YT help videos on how to add

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

to the file to get my internet working again, but I couldn't save the file properly.
First of all, it was empty by default which shouldn't be, I guess?
Second, after trying to exit and overwrite/save the file, it gives me an error saying "File or directory not found", which is weird since resolv.conf shows up running "ls" in "/etc/".

Although it shows up it is marked red, which shouldn't be as well, right?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/apC3l.jpg (can't add pictures into my posts yet, so imgur only - sorry).

Should I delete the file and create a new resolv.conf with that nameserver stuff in it? Is this even the right file?

I have no idea how I messed this up, so any help would be much appreciated.

_

Edit1: per request the output of running "ls -al /etc/resolv.conf" is as follows:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 27 Apr 24 15:12 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

both paths are marked red.

Edit2: unfortunately I don't have net-tools installed unless someone shows me how to download the net-tools package on windows and then install it on linux.

Comment: Btw, the internet works without any problems on my phone and win10 desktop, only my Linux laptop has this kind of connection problem.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 added the terminal output

Comment: Once name resolution is working again as per the duplicate, do: `sudo apt update` and then: `sudo apt install -y net-tools`

Comment: @chili555 my man, I can't access the internet - I can't update or download stuff. I'm currently answering on my main win10 desktop, not my Linux device that this thread is about ^^

Comment: Did you change the resolv.conf file and reboot as suggested? Is the link now correct? `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf`

Comment: @chili555 I did, after reboot it now says that ls has no access because the File or directory was not found.

Comment: It sounds like you got the rm part done but didn't do the ln part correctly. Please retrace your steps.

Comment: Please note: You will probably need: `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` That is, please preface the command with sudo.

Comment: @chili555 After running sudo ln it worked, kind of. Now when I run `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` it simply prints "/etc/resolv.conf" (highlighted in blue, if that's important)

Comment: Still not correct. Is systemd running? `sudo service systemd-resolved status | grep Active` Please do the entire sequence again: rm and then ln. Then show again: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` It *must* read: `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 32 Jun 15  2021 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf`

Comment: @chili555 Alright, it worked. it now reads `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Apr 24 16:59 /etc/resolv.conf -> /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf` - the path before the arrow is now blue whereas the path behind the arrow is normal white (which is good I guess?). I still can't connect to the internet tho, ping 8.8.8.8 "network not available" and ping google,com "temporary failure in name resolution".

Comment: That suggests that you aren't connected to the router. Can you click the Network Manager icon and connect? Do you have an IP address? `ip a`

Comment: @chili555 I do, I reconnected my laptop with the router and suddenly it worked. Finally, I have internet again. Even after a reboot everything works fine now. I can't thank you enough, this issue was driving me nuts for about a week now. May you have a wonderful rest of the day.

Comment: Woo hoo! Glad it’s working as expected!