# Both wifi and Ethernet not working

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet

I use ubuntu 20.04 on my ThinkPad x13 gen2, I am using the OEM kernel.
I recently had a failed update due to bad connection on the go. Since then I am not being able to use wifi. Network connects normally, but I can not really use the internet. I tried connecting it to Ethernet to make sure it's not a wifi issue. Same thing happened there. Without internet I'm not even being able to fix anything.
I rebooted into advanced mode and using root shell am able to connect to internet. Updated packages there. Worked without struggle.
What can I do to fix this? I'd rather not reinstall

Edit:
PING 8.8.8.8 result:

```
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 2027ms
```

resolv.conf

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Mar 14 18:54 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

ip a

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 84:a9:38:26:fe:43 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7c:70:db:1d:ec:3c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.160/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp0s20f3
       valid_lft 7130sec preferred_lft 7130sec
    inet6 fe80::f84d:e2dd:8ba4:c3ca/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

4: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none 
    inet 10.6.210.23/24 scope global wg0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

5: br-2047fd8b5f8b: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:47:2d:e9:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-2047fd8b5f8b
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

6: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:95:a3:cb:0c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:95ff:fea3:cb0c/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

7: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:06:ba:de:a3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

8: br-dfd4aebc6510: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:4e:03:9a:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.20.0.1/16 brd 172.20.255.255 scope global br-dfd4aebc6510
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

14: veth11fb4bb@if13: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master docker_gwbridge state UP group default 
    link/ether 72:4b:ad:ea:a7:ed brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 1
    inet6 fe80::704b:adff:feea:a7ed/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of these terminal commands: `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` and: `ls -al /etc/resolv.conf` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you for your response. I have added the things you asked for.

Comment: Your resolv.conf link is incorrect. Please change it: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150239/run-resolvconf-resolv-conf-ubuntu-18-04/1150294#1150294 Reboot and show us: `ip a` in an edit.

Comment: @chili555 thanks again. edited with ip a result

Comment: Sorry. I know nothing about dockers, bridges, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, wireguard vpn was the culprit. Purged it from system, network running smooth now.