# Netplan nameservers settings not used without resolv.conf entry

Tags: networking, dns, netplan, resolv.conf, systemd-resolved

I read [here](https://www.tecmint.com/set-permanent-dns-nameservers-in-ubuntu-debian/) that you're usually not supposed to edit resolv.conf, since it is managed by other services. The server is running Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

However, the DNS on my server is not working unless I put the following line in my resolv.conf

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
```

If I emtpy `resolv.conf` or remove the file entirely, I can no longer ping google.com.
I don't understand this, as I read [here](https://linux.die.net/man/5/resolv.conf):

> If this file does not exist, only the name server on the local machine will be queried

I want to use netplan to configure my network, and in my netplan config there's an entry for the nameservers. My netplan configuration looks like this:

```
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.0.0.5/24]
      nameservers:
        search: [my.domain.com]
        addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.254
```

There was a file called `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` but it has since been removed.

How can I have working DNS without manually editing the `resolv.conf` file?

Comment: Did you disable resolvconf / resolved's stub file?  Did you uninstall resolved?  Does `/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf` exist?  If you run `sudo ln -s /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf` does stuff work again?

Comment: 1. I don't know how. 2. No. 3. Yes. 4. Probably, but is that the way it is supposed to be set up?

Comment: That's one of the things that SystemD / ResolveD should be doing on its own.  It's possible that with no `/etc/systemd/resolved.conf` it's not picking it up, but it should not have been deleted, if it was deleted it's likely something else is installed taking over (resolvconf for instance) but that's not typical.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1150239/run-resolvconf-resolv-conf-ubuntu-18-04/1150294#1150294 Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @ThomasWard if you respond with an answer, I can resolve this question.